# How to add up the attribute of a nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have little issue with my logic here.

I have an accordion which I took a picture

[image]

the headers LIVE BETTING, MLB, MLB Props and NBA are here in the HTML (actually is a list of sports of almost 25 items)

```
  <accordion>
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="sport in sports">
      <accordion-heading>
        <div ng-click="addSportToLines(sport);">
          <span>{{sport.name}}</span>
          <span class="badge">{{sport.leagues.length}}</span>
        </div>
      </accordion-heading>

      <div>
        <a ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues"
           ng-click="addLeagueToLines(league)">
           <span>{{league.name}}</span>
           <span class="badge">{{league.offeringsAvailable}}</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

I need to delete the first `<span class=badge>` which contains `{{sport.leagues.length}}`  and put the sum of the `{{league.offeringsAvailable}}` there. The `{{league.offeringsAvailable}}` is the number in gray `badge`, that as you can see in MLB goes: 72,30,30,8,30

so in the yellow badge, instead of put `sport.leagues.length` I need the sum of `league.offeringsAvailable`

here is the controller for `sports`

```
SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues().then(function(sports) {
  $scope.sports = sports;
  console.log(angular.toJson($scope.sports, 'pretty'));
});
```

with this `console.log(angular.toJson($scope.sports, 'pretty'));` I get this json

as you see, the header, for example: LIVE BETTING which is the first one, contains an array `leagues` with a prop named `offeringsAvailable`, so I need to take every single `offeringsAvailable` inside let's say LIVE BETTING, and put the total amount in a `$scope` variable in order to display it in the DOM.

```
[
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "LIVE BETTING",
    "priority": 0,
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": "3042",
        "composedId": "3042G",
        "name": "NBA - Live",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 3,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3042",
        "composedId": "3044Q",
        "name": "NBA - Live (2Q)",
        "lineType": "Q",
        "part": 2,
        "offeringsAvailable": 2,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3042",
        "composedId": "3045Q",
        "name": "NBA - Live (3Q)",
        "lineType": "Q",
        "part": 3,
        "offeringsAvailable": 2,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3042",
        "composedId": "3046Q",
        "name": "NBA - Live (4Q)",
        "lineType": "Q",
        "part": 4,
        "offeringsAvailable": 2,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3068",
        "composedId": "3068G",
        "name": "Soccer - Live",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 41,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3295",
        "composedId": "3295G",
        "name": "MLB - Live",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 19,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3314",
        "composedId": "3314G",
        "name": "Tennis - Live",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 1,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6250",
        "composedId": "6250G",
        "name": "NHL - Live",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 4,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6250",
        "composedId": "6252P",
        "name": "NHL - Live (2P)",
        "lineType": "P",
        "part": 2,
        "offeringsAvailable": 2,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6250",
        "composedId": "6253P",
        "name": "NHL - Live (3P)",
        "lineType": "P",
        "part": 3,
        "offeringsAvailable": 2,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6711",
        "composedId": "6711G",
        "name": "NCAA Baseball - Live",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 1,
        "sport": {
          "id": 26
        }
      }
    ],
    "img": "images/icons/icon_live_betting.svg"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "MLB",
    "priority": 1,
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": "1496",
        "composedId": "1496G",
        "name": "MLB",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 72,
        "sport": {
          "id": 6
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "1496",
        "composedId": "1497I",
        "name": "MLB (1I)",
        "lineType": "I",
        "part": 1,
        "offeringsAvailable": 30,
        "sport": {
          "id": 6
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "1496",
        "composedId": "1498I",
        "name": "MLB (2I)",
        "lineType": "I",
        "part": 2,
        "offeringsAvailable": 30,
        "sport": {
          "id": 6
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "1721",
          "id": 6
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2012",
        "composedId": "2012T",
        "name": "MLB - Alternate Runlines",
        "lineType": "T",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 30,
        "sport": {
          "id": 6
        }
      }
    ],
    "img": "images/icons/icon_mlb.svg"
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "name": "MLB  Props",
    "priority": 2,
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": "6726",
        "composedId": "6726G",
        "name": "MLB Props - Runs+Hits+Error",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 15,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6727",
        "composedId": "6727G",
        "name": "MLB Props - Team to score 1st",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 15,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6728",
        "composedId": "6728G",
        "name": "MLB Props - 1st inning run?",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 15,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6731",
        "composedId": "6731G",
        "name": "MLB Props - 1st Called pitch",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 30,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6732",
        "composedId": "6732G",
        "name": "MLB Props - Players Matchups",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 30,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6741",
        "composedId": "6741G",
        "name": "MLB Props - 1st inning line",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 15,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      }
    ],
    "img": "images/icons/icon_mlb.svg"
  },
  ... "composedId": "1721T",
        "name": "MLB - Grand Salami",
        "lineType": "T",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 8,
        "sport": {
          "id": 6
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2012",
        "composedId": "2012T",
        "name": "MLB - Alternate Runlines",
        "lineType": "T",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 30,
        "sport": {
          "id": 6
        }
      }
    ],
    "img": "images/icons/icon_mlb.svg"
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "name": "MLB  Props",
    "priority": 2,
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": "6726",
        "composedId": "6726G",
        "name": "MLB Props - Runs+Hits+Error",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 15,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6727",
        "composedId": "6727G",
        "name": "MLB Props - Team to score 1st",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 15,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6728",
        "composedId": "6728G",
        "name": "MLB Props - 1st inning run?",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 15,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6731",
        "composedId": "6731G",
        "name": "MLB Props - 1st Called pitch",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 30,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6732",
        "composedId": "6732G",
        "name": "MLB Props - Players Matchups",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 30,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6741",
        "composedId": "6741G",
        "name": "MLB Props - 1st inning line",
        "lineType": "G",
        "part": 0,
        "offeringsAvailable": 15,
        "sport": {
          "id": 41
        }
      }
    ],
    "img": "images/icons/icon_mlb.svg"
  },
  ...
```

I am using `LODASH` to iterate over arrays. But I don't have an idea of how I can accomplish this task

**EDIT**

Do not get confuse because I mentioned above LIVE BETTING, I mean, I want the same to happen with every sport in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
// in view, replace
{{sport.leagues.length}}

// with
{{ total(sport) }}

//in controller, add scope method
$scope.total = function(sport) {
    return _.sum(_.pluck(sport.leagues, 'offeringsAvailable'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest just looping over each sport when you receive data and add an `offerings` property that contains the sum

```
sports.forEach(function(sport){ 
    sport.offerings=sport.leagues.reduce(function(prev,curr){     
        return prev + (curr.offeringsAvailable||0);
    },0);
});
```

Then in the header use `{{sport.offerings}}`